# Getting 500 Error in admn grid edit form

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-500

I transferred site into my dev server and now when I open CMS pages and click on grid item it shows me this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error - http://test.com/admin/cms_page/edit/page_id/3/key/0299dda10356a2de9059101b0355ab50/

It only happens when I click on edit grid item and click on "create new". What is causing this error?

Comment: Please clarify add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I transferred my magento site into my dev server and its working fine but when i click editing or creating new cms page from admin it give me above error and page breaks down.

Comment: have u updated the secure and unsecure baseurl in magento admin or in database